# how to dynamically share global config variables across packages

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

There is tons of literature about how to share config settings across files, modules, etc...but my question is a bit different.

What is the pythonic way to share a config setting across python packages that don't know about each other?

I have a scenario, where due to various technical limitations, I've had to split my code up into 3 packages.

I have:

1. package(s) for a python 3 flask app
2. package(s) for a scrapy web scraper app (python 2.7)
3. base db models package used by #1 and #2

#1 and #2 know about #3, but #3 does not and should not know about #1 and #2.

Because I'm using Flask, I'm also using Flask-SQLAlchemy. Flask-SQLAlchemy creates a nice little `db` object for you that is similar to straight SQLAlchemy's `Base = declarative_base()` Base object.

This means all my model objects in #3 are declared using `db.Model`. But #3 doesn't have a `db` object itself. It needs to get the `db` object for the package using it, #1 or #2.

Basically in #3, I want to import `db` dynamically via:

```
db = __import__(global_config_name_of_pkg, globals(), locals(), ['db'], -1).db
```

#1 and #2 will be responsible for setting `global_config_name_of_pkg`.

I've considered just setting a property on `__builtins__`, and grabbing the value from there, but that seems very unpythonic and I also believe the name has changed between python 2 and 3 -- `__builtin__` vs `__builtins__`.

Any suggestions on how to go about achieving this?

Thanks!

## Update:

Why has this question been marked a duplicate? It's not! The link to the dupcliate question is completely different from the question I'm asking.

*I'm not asking how to share SQLAlchemy models between flask and other apps at all. I'm already sharing SQLAlchemy models between different 'apps' just  fine.*

I just provided that as context. Perhaps the context I gave hid my question which was the ***very*** second sentence in my post.

The question stands as is:  *What is the pythonic way to share a config setting across python packages that don't know about each other?*

If you plan to close again, please justify.

Comment: Try Redis? https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis

Comment: Ah, thanks @Celeo! That's actually a very interesting idea. I'll be using redis for other stuff. On its own I think it may be a bit overkill for just passing around 1 or 2 config variables, but since I'll be using redis anyway, this is pretty good idea.  For now, __builtins__ might not be pythonic, but it's working very well.